# Java NFC tag app for Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, debian, nfc

I'm looking for a working Java tutorial app that reads an NFC tag on a Desktop (NOT Android - that's easy!). My goal is to have an simple app that can read the url from an NFC tag. I prefer Java, but anything is fine.

So far nfctools looks promising, but I can't find a simple reader based on it.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and have pcsc_scan reading raw data from the dongle, and libtools' nfc-probe to detect the card/nfc, but I'm after something much higher level.

Comment: NFC is still pretty new, so maybe you could create a higher-level library and post it as open-source for others to use?

Answer (score 0):

I would ask you to try this

https://github.com/grundid/nfctools

and examples for these to get you started

https://github.com/grundid/nfctools-examples

> == NFC Tools for Java ==
>
> NFCTools is a collection of libraries and tools for NFC in Java.  The
>   targeted devices are desktop Reader/Writer and Android smart phones.
>
> Most functions in the library have been tested with a  Nexus S running
>   ICS and a ACR 122 USB NFC dektop reader.
>
> The NDEF tag functions work with Mifare classic 1K and 4K cards and
>   Ultralight/C (Type2) tags.
>
> You can find a live Demo Applet using these tools and some YouTube
>   videos at: http://www.grundid.de/nfc/
>
> An online NDEF Editor using this library is also available at:
>   http://ndefeditor.com